# Css swap based on URL

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to load different css in angular depending on the url and its sub url.

This is my attempt:
also tried /recruiter/*

```
 var memberPage = $location.path('/recruiter/account');
            var defaultPage = $location.path('/');

            if(memberPage){
                vm.style = '/Content/css/styles-recruiter';
            } else if (defaultPage){
                vm.style = '/Content/css/styles';
            }
```

html:

```
<link ng-href="{{vm.style}}.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: You don't specify `recruiterPage` in your code.

Comment: What is vm? What is recruiterPage?

Comment: @Wavemaster Yeah I did just change it for this post.

Comment: Use UI-router and lazy loading. Set the Css in the router config for that route.